# AttributeError: module 'numpy.linalg._umath_linalg' has no attribute '_ilp64'

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk

Running this code block on google colab. **"import nltk" is causing the issue.**

```
Error Statement:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py in <module>
     55 IS_PYSTON = hasattr(sys, "pyston_version_info")
     56 HAS_REFCOUNT = getattr(sys, 'getrefcount', None) is not None and not IS_PYSTON
---> 57 HAS_LAPACK64 = numpy.linalg._umath_linalg._ilp64
     58 
     59 _OLD_PROMOTION = lambda: np._get_promotion_state() == 'legacy'

**AttributeError: module 'numpy.linalg._umath_linalg' has no attribute '_ilp64'**
```

```
import sys
import numpy as np
#!pip uninstall -y numpy
#!pip install numpy
!pip install setuptools
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings
import csv
import urllib.parse as parse
import pickle
!pip uninstall -y nltk
!pip install nltk
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from urllib.parse import unquote
```

How to rectify the same?

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling both numpy and nltk. I also tried to upgrade them but the same error persists.

Comment: What are your `numpy` and  `nltk` versions?

Comment: https://github.com/deeppavlov/DeepPavlov/issues/1460#issuecomment-1094190974

Comment: I think this has some thing to do with version compatibility. I also saw that I had this error in relation to this:

A NumPy version >=1.21.6 and <1.28.0 is required for this version of SciPy (detected version 1.21.4 -